# Get the minimum of a function using numpy fmin within limits

Tags: python, numpy, minimize, curve-fitting

I need to constrained minimization of some data (ie so that I get the minimum value within a certain range). Currently I can only get the minimum over all of space. For example, if valid possible answers for the problem at hand are only in the range -5<=x<=5, then having fmin tell me the minimum of the function is at -10505 is useless. I need restrict the possible output to within the problem limits.

```
        p = [0,0,0]
        fit_quad = lambda p,w: p[2]*w**2 + p[1]*w + p[0]
        errfunc = lambda p,l,w: fit_quad(p,w) - l
        fit, success = leastsq(errfunc, p, args=(y,x), maxfev=5000) #x and y are the input datasets
        #find the minimum tilt
        quad = lambda w,p: p[2]*w**2 + p[1]*w + p[0]
        min_tilt = fmin(quad, 0.0, args=([fit]))[0]
        #check for range violations
        if min_tilt < min_angle #the minimum on the quadratic can sometimes end up negative, especially if there are not enough good points
            min_tilt = 0.0
        elif min_tilt > max_angle: #if things are extremely tilted the minimum of the fit quadratic can end up unrealistically high. This pulls it back.
            min_tilt = max_angle
```

Note that just setting a simple check for above or below as in the above is not enough. I can end up on the wrong side of the range depending on the precise part of the function that is inside the range.

Answer (score 1):

Use [fmin_cobyla](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html) or [fmin_slsqp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html).

Comment: A question: with eg `fmin_cobyla`, how do you define the constraint function if you want eg `10 < param < 100` instead of simple `param > 0`?

Comment: Define two constraint functions, one for `100 - param > 0` and one for `param - 10 > 0`.

Answer (score -1):

your can filter your data:

```
ll = np.array([100,20,-30,1,2,3,4,5])

min(np.array(filter(lambda x:-5 < x < 5, ll)))
```

Comment: The OP, needs a constrained minimization, this doesn't do that.

Comment: Whosh, seriously the question is by far to convoluted. The word constraint maximization is not mentioned.

Comment: Wasn't sure what the terminology was.